# How to retrieve reward point amount for order using REST API in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, rest-api

The Magento 2 (Enterprise) REST API for endpoint: `/V1/orders/{entity_id}` is missing the field containing the redeemed reward points for an order, called `reward_currency_amount`.

I have checked the Swagger doc and pulled requests into Postman, but don't see anything matching that field.

How can I retrieve the redeemed reward amount for an order via API method?

REST API JSON structure for order request:
https://jsfiddle.net/4rua50cd/

Sample JSON from application:
https://jsfiddle.net/ce83wfo0/

Comment: You may need to include a new extension attribute. But let me confirm that after I have a quick look at the response. Can you update the post with the sample response of the order API call.

Comment: I posted this issue with Magento support and they responded that making the reward_currrency_amount available in the REST response is in their backlog of features and they have no ETA when it will be available. That means we need to figure this out on our own.